# how can you use a gmail script to attach more than one image at a time. below is an example of a working script to attach one image

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to set up a Google Sheet with some data to email images.  I have the code working below to send a single image attachment but I would like to send more than one image at a time if it is possible.  How could I change the code below to work with multiple images?

```
 function emailImage(){
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
   // Fetch the range of cells
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)  
   var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var subject = row[1];       // Second column
    var message = row[2];       // Third column
    var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3]).getBlob();   // Fourth column
    var emailSent = row[4];     // Fifth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [image]});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the image is in an array?

Comment: @MetaMan I don't know what an array is.  So no I didn't notice.  I was just looking for a good simple answer to my question if there was one.

Comment: That is a simple answer.  Trying getting another image and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it onto the array.  It's time to learn about arrays

Comment: @MetaMan Thanks for responding I really appreciate the help. I'm a complete newbie at this and are just adapting using code found online (above).  If it is possible to 'try and get  another image and 'push' it onto the array'  I would have no idea how to do that.  Could you please give me a code example.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with me giving you code examples is that you never end up learning how to figure this stuff out on your own.  No doubt someone will come along and provide you with a freebie answer but today it won't be me.

Comment: @metaman that is totally up to you and I understand.  I'm not really trying hard enough I guess.  I've got a lot more work both in front and behind this code above and are just looking for help.  I'm not really looking to learn all about arrays and everything code myself right now when there are people like yourself that have the easy answer to my newbie question.  It may seem like I'm not trying, but in fact I'm trying a whole hell of a lot or I wouldn't be doing this without any knowledge to begin with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232364/discussion-between-brett-and-metaman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a snippet to help you along:

```
  var image1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3]).getBlob();
  var image2 = 'However you wish to get it';
  var options = { attachments: [] }; 
  option.attachments.push(image1);
  option.attachments.push(image2);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, options);
```

Comment: I do so appreciate your help.  I'm such a stupid rookie though that unless the code is all there I'm not going to figure out what is missing.  I can usually adjust things to make them work for my project and I've tried with this several times...  I simply added it where I thought it should go, but that did not work.  So I thought maybe to add inside the attachment brackets [image1, image2] because I remember seeing that somewhere, but that didn't work either.. I'm going to try somemore stuff now... thanks.

Comment: Thanks! NAN (not an answer) flag retracted.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @MetaMan I was finally able to get this working....

```
function emailImage(){
 var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
   // Fetch the range of cells
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6)  
   var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var subject = row[1];       // Second column
    var message = row[2];       // Third column
    var image1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3]).getBlob();
    var image2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[4]).getBlob();
    var emailSent = row[5];     // Fifth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [image1, image2]});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good job.  I'm glad you worked it out.  Knowing how has always been worth the journey of learning.  Although sometimes doesn't feel like it will when you're on the journey.